# Define data type of a numpy array when wrapping an existing C library with cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I'm new to cython and I'm a bit lost when I need to define a type for my numpy array when wrapping an existing C library (foolib). This library uses a defined type for the int size depending on the platform and if it has been built in 32 or 64 bits.

Here is one excerpt of `foolib.h`:

```
#include "footypes.h"
...
int foo_zone_read(int fn, int B, int Z, char *zonename, foosize_t *size);
```

Here is what is found in `footypes.h`:

```
# if FOO_BUILD_64BIT
# define FOO_SIZEOF_SIZE    64
   typedef long foosize_t;
# else
#  define FOO_SIZEOF_SIZE    32
   typedef int foosize_t;
# endif
```

I have also the cython wrapper. Here is the cython header `foolib.pxd`:

```
cdef extern from "foolib.h":
    ctypedef int foosize_t
    ...
    int foo_zone_read(int fn, int B, int Z, char *zonename, foosize_t *size)
```

And the actual cython wrapper `bar.pyx`:

```
import numpy
cimport numpy
cimport foolib
...
cdef class pyFOO(object):

   def __init__(self, filename)
        pass

    cpdef zone_read(self, int B, int Z):
        cdef char zonename[MAXNAMELENGTH]
        cdef int *zsize
        cdef int ztype_read
        cdef numpy.ndarray[cgsize_t, ndim=1] azsize
```

On the last line I have a cython error when I try to compile:

```
cdef numpy.ndarray[cgsize_t, ndim=1] azsize
                          ^    
------------------------------------------------------------

bar.pyx:285:31: Invalid type.
```

I tried to read the C-API numpy reference but I'm a little bit lost. All I want is to type `asize` with the correct type. I know that on linux it would be `dtype=int32` or `dtype=int64` depending on the compilation of foolib. If I would have created the array like this: `asize=numpy.ones(2, dtype=numpy.int64)` it would have worked, but now the type is hardcoded and I don't want that.

So my question is how do I get the correct type by passing the information somehow between footypes.h ans the numpy array.
My secondary question is how do I specify the size of my numpy array (if I do it in python syntax it's easy, but with the numpy C-API it's not clear to me). I know that it can be an array of shape (2) or (6) depending on the runtime conditions.

Thanks in advance.